# How to render a HTML tag from json value using angularJs

Tags: html, json, angularjs

// json is like this

```
"_unparsedString": "<p>test<\/p>"
```

//  HTML

```
<div>Preamble : '{{item2._unparsedString}}'</div>
```

//Output

```
Preamble : <p>test<\/p>
```

but how to render that tag and display it using angular ?

//Output should be like this

```
 Preamble : test
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of passing string to view directly, you should use [sce.trustAsHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml) to pre-process the html.

```
$scope.bindHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml(item2._unparsedString);
```

Then in your view template, use ng-bind-html to handle html binding.

```
<div>Preamble : <div ng-bind-html="bindHTML"></div></div>
```

As you mentioned you have an array of object, it's not that easy to cast them in your controller, you can bind `$sce` to your `$scope` then call `trustAsHtml` in your view

So in your controller

```
myapp.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http, $filter, $sce) {
   $scope.$sce = $sce;
...
}
```

Then in your html view

```
<div>Preamble {{$index+1}} : <span ng-bind-html="$sce.trustAsHtml(item1.Preamble._unparsedString)"></span></div>
```

Comment: i'm having array of objects..so how to apply it bcoz its not a single value..and i have to apply inside a ng-repeat

Comment: @Flash check out my update. You can just inject `$sce` into your controller.

Comment: @Flash see https://jsfiddle.net/1joo0j77/5/  run the project, pick "Markets" in second select box. You can see the result.

Answer (score 5):

Please check this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Shital_D/b9qtj56p/6/

Download file - angular-sanitize.js and include it in your app.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngSanitize"]);       

app.controller('myController', function($scope,$compile) {
    $scope.html = '<p>Your html code</p>';
});

<div ng-app="myApp">
     <div ng-controller="myController">
     <p ng-bind-html="html"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It Worked , But what is different between angular_js and angular-sanitize.js